# How to map Gmail's "delete conversation" shortcut to use the actual "delete" key instead of the pound # key

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

I use Gmail's web application and I would like to delete a conversation by pressing the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key on my keyboard. By default, the delete shortcut is <kbd>#</kbd>.

I found the **"Keyboard Shortcuts"** section in Gmail settings. I know how to map this delete feature to any key except the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key. I tried to type **DEL** in the Custom keyboard shortcut section but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Mail Keyboard Shortcut for delete on Mac](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/google-mail-keyboard-shortcut-for-delete-on-mac)

Comment: Related [I can't seem to get the shortcut key (#) for deleting to work in Gmail on OSx](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29402/88163)

Comment: No sorry this is not my question. The default shortcut works for me. But I want to replace it by the `DEL` key.

Comment: Have you read the answer or the first link? --> "You can also remap your keys with the Google Labs feature : Custom keyboard shortcuts" Some of the answers to the other linked question also mention the use a Gmal Lab.

Comment: Yes Rubén I have read the answers and I know how to map this feature with any key except the `DEL` key. This is why my question was only related to the `DEL` key of the keyboard. I tried to type DEL in the Custom keyboard shortcut section but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange is removing the symbol when posting. It's working for me. I looked up the [ASCII no.](https://bytetool.web.app/en/ascii/) for delete, it's 127, then used an [ASCII number to char converter](https://www.browserling.com/tools/ascii-to-text) to obtain the symbol.

Note that the display of this symbol may appear blank on your screen, but it is indeed there.

Comment: This answer could be improved. It seems to lack some context. It is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This Chrome extension worked for me: [Delete Key for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/delete-key-for-gmail/alpohlaboohebmblbmanccbepncahbda)

Use the <kbd>delete</kbd> key without  a modifier key like this:

[image]

Note that it seems to work while the email is open, but not in list view.  I suspect the extension could be modified to support list view.  You could contact the developer via the Support section on the extension page if that is a feature you need.